# ToastBar in postResponse of connectionRequest

Tags: codenameone

`ToastBar` when I use in any part of the code, it works fine, but when I use it to show some message that connection is completed ie. use it in `postResponse` of `connectionRequest`, it doesn't show. Why?

```
public boolean abc = false;
ConnectionRequest cr = new ConnectionRequest(){
    @Override
    protected void postResponse() {
        abc = true;
        //update: this toastbar is commented 
        ToastBar.showMessage("Confirmation of your password is sent to your email address", FontImage.MATERIAL_MAIL_OUTLINE,2000);
    }

};
cr.setPost(true);
cr.setUrl(AllUrl.forgetPasswordUrl);
cr.setDuplicateSupported(true);
cr.setTimeout(30000);
cr.addArgument("forgetten_email", forgottonEmail);
InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
Dialog d = ip.showInifiniteBlocking();
cr.setDisposeOnCompletion(d);
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(cr);
```

Update1:
It is a form created in Gui builder as blank dialog. The toastbar doesnot work here but another dialog box works

```
protected void beforeForgetPasswordDialog(Form f) {
    TextField emailTextField = new TextField();
    f.add(emailTextField);

    Button submit = new Button("Submit");

    submit.addActionListener(e -> {
        Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Label");
        String forgottenPasswordEmail = emailTextField.getText();
        if (forgottenPasswordEmail != null && !forgottenPasswordEmail.equals("")) {
            ForgetPasswordConnection fpc = new ForgetPasswordConnection();
            fpc.forgetPasswordConnectionMethod(forgottenPasswordEmail, s, StateMachine.this, f);
            forgetPasswordSuccess = fpc.abc;
            if (forgetPasswordSuccess) {
                showForm("Main", null);
            }
        } else {
         //Dialog.show(null, "Email id is empty", "ok", null);
//Dialogbox works here, but toastBar doesnt work
        //  f.addShowListener(d -> {
        //  ToastBar.showMessage("Email id is empty", FontImage.MATERIAL_MAIL_OUTLINE, 2000);
        //  });                
        }
    });
    f.add(submit);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the method is invoked before the dialog is disposed so you are showing the toastbar on the dialog instead of the parent form. Try keeping a reference to the current form and then add a show listener to that e.g.:

```
parentForm.addShowListener(e -> showMyToastbar());
```

Comment: ok now I have a real problem. I have called this connectionRequest in a form which is actually a blank dialog created in GUI builder and here addShowListener also doesnot do the trick.